# Does the current passing through a pass-through Powerline adapter affects its speed?

Tags: networking, internet, powerline-networking, wired-networking

At my livingroom I have a powerline adapter that connects to the only power socket near my modem, which of course needs an extension so I can connect more appliances to it. I have indeed connected most of my entertainment devices including my TV to that extension and the powerline is connected to the most direct route to the power socket.

To get better performance I am thinking on getting a Pass-Through adapter to replace the existing one:

> [image: powerline adapter]

My question is: Since I have so many devices connected to the same power socked drawing quite a lot of current, will this affect the performance of the powerline adapter? Will it be the same as using the extension that I already have in place?

Cheers!

Comment: I think these things are often not very well understood by most people including me and including most techies, and your best bet might be to test it with just one item and with more and see if the LAN speed degrades. You may find that for some reason you don't get a good speed even with one item in there.  I'd bet that if other items in there did degrade speed, it wouldn't be because of current getting used, though I don't know.I don't know if one model would differ from another or if  performance changes depending on what plug point it's in. But these/issues may exist so it's best to test

Comment: Alternating current (AC) at 60 Hertz should have no affect on powerline performance.  But the type of devices that are plugged in nearby could.  Simple appliances such as incandescent lights or space heater should generate no electrical noise.  Electronic devices with switched-mode power supplies can generate EMI, both in the air (i.e. radio waves) and back into the power line.  The permitted airborne EMI is regulated, but manufacturers have been know to try to skirt the rules (e.g. products with fake FCC tags).  Try plugging all the other devices into a power strip with noise filters.

Comment: If you aren't exceeding rated current or popping a circuit breaker, the AC current has no impact on the powerline data signal.